# Django form field initial strfrtime value not updating

Tags: django, forms, time, django-forms, initialization

I have a Django form field, for a time, where I set the initial value to the current time by using the time.strfrtime() function.

Using this method, the field is initially populated correctly with the current time when I first load the Django app (by executing python manage.py runserver). However, subsequently if I reload the page, the form field fails to update the current time, instead repeatedly spitting back the time the app was first started. However, if I modify one of my Django files, such as forms.py or views.py, then the current time is correctly refreshed.

In forms.py:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):

      end_time = forms.TimeField(label="Current time",   initial=strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

In views.py:

```
def index(request):

    event_form = EventForm()
```

How do I get the end_time field's initial value to always update to the current time?

Note: I'm aware I can fix this by passing in initial data to my event_form = EventForm() code, such as:

```
event_form = EventForm(initial={'end_time':strftime("%I:%M %p")})
```

But is there a better way? What's going on behind the scenes that the current time won't update automatically itself?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set it in `__init__()` method of the class.

```
from time import strftime
from django import forms


class EventForm(forms.Form):
    end_time = forms.TimeField(label='Current time')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(initial={
            'end_time': strftime('%I:%M %p')
        })

        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Do you know why you can't just set it in the field definition/attributes as I originally had it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its because the class variables are instantiated only the first time you create an instance of this class. Therefore you have the ability to overload the initialising method to change what you need.